# Daily forecasting using ARIMA in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am new to time series modeling in R. I have sales data of one year and three months only. I am trying to do sales forecasting at the day level or max at the week level. Following is the step I intend to follow

1. Convert it into time series object using `ts(data$qty, frequency= ??)`. Here I am very confused about frequency. I can see in data that there is some seasonality like sales is picking up in May, June, July and then again in festival seasons. I guess I cannot use 365 as I have only one year data. Please suggest what should be the frequency
2. Decompose the time series. Subtract the seasonality and trend from the actual time series model
3. Fit ARIMA to get a prediction
4. Again add seasonality and trend to output the final forecast

Please provide feedback on this if its correct approach or not or if there is any other better way to handle it.

Comment: Trust me when I say this. If you're going to analyze seasonality and time series in general you need > 2 observations per time unit ( may it be days, weeks or months).

Comment: This is true Dr. Mike, but if you only have 1 year and 3 months you will have to use it...we recommend 3 years for daily so you can get a read on holidays as there would have been a weekend and a weekday read.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Mike .. I understand now the error in my approach . what do you suugest should be the best approach

Answer (score 2):

No need to subtract any seasonality.

I would recommend using a regression model with NO ARIMA component. Bring in 6 day of the week dummy variables, 11 month of the year variables, holiday variables while searching for outliers, level shifts, trend. Removing variables ("stepdown") that are not necessary and bringing ("stepup") in dummies for the outliers I listed.

We recommend using 3 years of data in order for holidays to exist on weekends and weekdays so that you can get an overall read on the lead and lag relationships. You can also search for day of the month dummy variables, but this is typically only necessary for CASH demand type problems. You can find the need to specify a week of the month dummy for special cases as well.

You can build a pivot table in Excel to compare the coefficients in the model to the % of the total for the day of the week and month of the year to get a "poor man's model" to confirm that the coefficients make sense.

Comment: Thanks Tom for replying. I understand it is difficult to handle seasonality with one year data. I am trying the regression approach suggested by you and will share the result. Also I was trying to fit arima simply. I was informed by my clients that they are getting good result from moving average only . So I thought ARIMA will for sure improve on that. Any Comment on this approach

Comment: We agree that it is difficult with such a short dataset, but these are the cards you were dealt. ARIMA lag 7 could be used, but if you consider forecasting accuracy from many origins you might see disaster around holidays.  Post your data and state the starting date and country where the data resides and we can take a look.

Comment: You can also post your model and results to dropbox.com

Comment: Thanks Tom , I am trying the regression approach as it will help the client to visualize the seasonality in a better way(by coefficient of different months and days of week as well). But one small question how to handle yearly growth . As the business is new I can see there is decent growth in volume of business from last year. I have included the monthly dummy variables, days of week , holidays and even daily promotional offers. But still results is not coming in the desirable variance. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Pankaj,  You can use a trend variable (ie 1,2,3,4,etc) as a regressor. The trend variable is a surrogate, but it is trying to handle something that you are not in terms of explanatory power. For example, you can include a causal variable that can help like "# of stores" or "# of sales reps" and future values of stores which can explain that "growth" provide "guidance" to the forecast.  You likely are not handling other issues that I have mentioned already (ie outliers,  lead/lags before holidays).  I see you did not post your data.  You can scale the data to anonyomize!! Still the same model!

Comment: Thanks Tom ,I am doing the outliers treatment and also using a latent variable to tag those events. I am new to stackflow. Really don't know how to put post data here

Comment: Open an account with dropbox.com and post the data there and then the link here.  Post any output that you have in Excel or text file....actuals, your causals fit and your model.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n94e0it09l4eslu/totdata1.csv ... have put the daily data here . The data belongs of a wholesale shop for delhi , india region – pankaj jha 10 mins ago edit

Comment: This is good, but can you label what variables you are actually using in the model. Highlight them in red?  Also highlight what the Y variable is.  I like that you are trying to use a causal to explain the history like "numofuniqcustproductlevel".  You will have to provide a forecast of this as required by regression.  It also seems like you might be bringing in too many of these (ie dist_invnogrplevel).  Columns AJ to AL make no sense to use in a regression.  Maybe you are not using these?  Again, I need to see what you actually want to use.  Do any have a known lead or lag relationship?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n94e0it09l4eslu/totdata1.csv.... the variables marked in red are target and marked in grey are used in model. I am not using variable AJ to AL. Lag depends a lot on different variables usually a weeks lag is good as suggested by my clients. As of now I have not used any lag. Also I need weekly prediction. Thanks for the help Tom.

Comment: Pankaj, It looks like the file wasn't uploaded properly.  Please check.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq1u1qzhreedlwy/totdata1.xlsx .... Please check this link

Comment: Pankaj,  Your data set has missing observations.  If there was zero volume you still need to consider it.  A time series by definition is observations over an equally spaced period of time.  For example, you have no March 1, 2012 or March 2,2012.  There are 11 days you are missing.  Also, you have no holiday variables.  That is fine if you think that there is no impact, but highly doubt that they are not important. Report to dropbox when you are ready.

Comment: the sales figure for these 11 days is missing . Before fitting a model I replaced it with the average of March months. I removed it from the data provided to you so that you could suggest somthing else as treatment. I will do the same in the data kept at dropbox. For holiday I have created a field in column AH.

Comment: Please, consider creating a chat room to continue this discussion.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq1u1qzhreedlwy/totdata1.xlsx.... Done Tom. I have replaced the missing value with the average of that month. Please let me know if you like the missing value in any other way .

Comment: Pankaj, You need to have a column for each holiday.  Otherwise you are assuming that the impact is the same. Please adjust the file and name the holidays at the top of the column. Chl---I am in the US and pankaj is in india...we are responding infrequenly...pankaj...contact me at tomreilly@autobox.com

Comment: Tom,
When you recommended "a regression model with NO ARIMA" do you mean using a simple multi-variate linear regression model by creating those dummy variables for week/month?

Comment: Yes.  you can try it both ways and see which way you like better.